# How do you change hint text color in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I cannot get the hint text color to change in my Android application on the log in page.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1" />
```

I use the textColorHint method as found in many other examples online but I do not know what is wrong with what I am doing.

Comment: Are your background color and text color both white?

Comment: Override in your app theme `<item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>` in your `styles.xml` this will globally set the default colour.

Comment: It works to change it in the styles.xml. Not sure why it doesn't change when I try to edit it in my layout file.  But this should work. Thanks you guys for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Use attribute `android:textColorHint="YOUR_COLOR"` to set hints text color.

In your `AutoCompleteTextView`, you are using `WHITE` color for `textColor`, `backgroundTint` and `textColorHint`. Make sure your `AutoCompleteTextView` background color is different from `WHITE`.

Here is an working example for `AutoCompleteTextView`. I have used `RED` color for `textColor`, `GREEN` color `backgroundTint` and `BLUE` color for `textColorHint`.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:backgroundTint="#00FF00"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Write something..."
    android:textColorHint="#0000FF"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Hope this will help you~

Comment: I tried to get the example you used above to work and all of the colors change except for the hint text, it is the default black.  Any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: I think there is a problem in your styles.xml. Can you please post your style xml?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the text  in the layout's EditText            android:textColorHint = "@android:color/     then press ctrl+space and choice your color.